# how do i create an html file in document root and after that open it in my browser

Tags: html, linux, apache

How do I find DocumentRoot directory in CentOS and then create an HTML file into that directory? How to open that file through my browser?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to install web server in your system.
Default DocumentRoot Directory is /var/www/html for apache web server. 
So if you have installed apache web server then you need to create html file in /var/www/html/ directory using any editor like vi/nano.

If you don't have any domain then you can access that file in browser using that server ip. 
http://x.x.x.x/index.html
if that is your local system then you can access it using 
http://localhost/index.html

Answer (score 0):

To Find Apache DocumentRoot  in CentoS system use grep command as follow:

> grep -i 'DocumentRoot' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

sample output should be :

> > DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
>
> DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
>
> > access content that does not live under the DocumentRoot.

Then go to that  directory (For example /var/www/html) by typing:

> cd /var/www/html

Then create html file inside it with name index.html as following:

> vi index.html

type simple words like (Hello world) then save and exit the file

Finally, To Open that file through your browser (firefox) type the next command and hit enter:

> firefox file:///var/www/html/index.html